# What can I do to serve text-based webpages more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, web

For context I am trying to get a webserver up and running with low specs (think Raspberry Pi level) and want it to serve text content to as many users as possible.

I have tried looking up general tips, and this was [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323226/compressing-entire-webpages-html-and-js)...but I can't believe that it's completely pointless to use Javascript to de-encode a website that's been compressed. If I took a simple cipher to replace each instance of '`<div`' with a special character I know I would never serve (some of [these](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_currency.asp) maybe), wouldn't I already be saving some bandwidth? A JS search and replace on the client side can't take more than a fraction of a second.

So my question is are any of these novel methods for speeding up simple websites worth it in the end? Are there other methods I am not considering?

Comment: Your web server will compress better than anything you could cook up. Try nginx ... for the Pi https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/nginx.md

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficiently" , "low specs" ? Compared to ?

Comment: Its a little confusing to know what you are trying to optimize.

Comment: You don't need JS to compress your pages. [HTTP already handles that for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)! And no, it's not novel.

Comment: I figured something like this already had to have been done. I just wasn't sure what. Thanks for the quick responses guys

Comment: Basically what I meant by low-spec would be I'd be pushing it to 100% all the time. I wanted to see if there was anything extra I could do, when my server supports 500 users, to make it support 520 or 530. Also thanks @Wainage, I'll take a look at that

Comment: See also https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Comment: @bigmack on a low spec device, 500 active users is a lot. I think you are running into the problem of over-optimizing when you don't know where the bottle neck is or could be. There are ways to test server load and I would point you that way and figure out how your application behaves before going into theories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http-protocoll supports gzip compression natively. There is no further benefit in replacing
"<div " with "x". In order to improve performance you can tell your web-server to serve files that are already gzip-compressed. I did that once and it cut down page loading time about 10 milliseconds on a shared hoster using apache.